# Dual NIC Windows 7 on LAN with seperate DNS

Tags: windows-7, dns

I have a Windows 7 machine with two NICs and that sits on two LANs (neither is connected to the internet).

On one LAN the DNS seems to work just fine, I am able to reach other computers on that LAN via computer name. However, I can't reach machines on the second LAN via name, but IP address does work.

Is there a way to set it up so Windows 7 is able to reach computers on both networks via name?

After some investigation it seems that the DNS server on the second network doesn't respond.  I do a nslookup computername DNS-IP  (replacing the two options with a computer on the network and the ip of the DNS) and I get a timeout.  I can ping the DNS computer, so I can talk to it but it won't respond to the DNS request.  The same command on a computer just on the second network works as expected (returning the DNS info).

Both LANs have their own domain controller.  I login to Windows using the first network's domain controller, could the second network (the one I can't get DNS from) be causing problems becuase I am not logged in to there domain controller?

Comment: I would troubleshoot the DNS server on network 2 and see why it's not allowing DNS lookups.  Firewall?  DNS service stopped?  Is DNS even installed on it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like DNS is not properly configures on one of the two NICs.

- Open the `Control Panel`
- Type `Network and Sharing` in the upper right hand corner search box and hit `Enter`
- Click `Change Adapter Settings`
- `Right click` on the network adapter you are having issues with and click `Properties`.  If you don't know which one is the problem, you might have to look at the properties for both and deduce which is the NIC with the DNS issue
- Select `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)` and click the `Properties` button
- The bottom box of the Properties shows DNS information.  If you receive your IP automatically from a DHCP server (top box of dialog), then more than likely, you should use `Obtain DNS server address automatically`.  However, if you do not, select the opther option, `Use the follwing DNS server addresses` and enter in the preferred and alternate DNS server address.

Comment: I had the above already set as described.  I have the DNS server for the second network set and I can ping it.  I verified it was the right DNS server for that network.